# How to calculate fee when dealing with different decimals token?

Tags: solidity, remix, evm

I'm kinda struggling here to find a solution.

I have a code where user can deposit token like USDC, DAI etc...

For example USDC had 6 decimals and DAI has 18 decimals.

How can I have a generic fee calculation in my function so it handle all different case when decimals are differents and also avoid rounding by 0 ?

I have something like this for the calculation :

```
uint256 feeToCollect = (amount * feeBps * 10**18) / BPS; 

uint256 amountWithFee = amount + fee; 

IERC20(token).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amountWithFee;
```

> amount = amount that the user deposit
>
> feeBps = 10 so it's 0.1%
>
> BPS = 10000
>
> 10**18 is a scale to avoid rounding by 0.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Don't hardcode the decimal value, get it dynamically from `IERC20(token).decimals();`

Comment: Correct thanks but I have the following issue when I increment the deposited amount and the fees :

Let say I deposit 100 tokens and have 2 mapping that keep track of the deposit and fees : 

mapping(address => uint256) public totalDeposited;
mapping(address => uint256) public feeCollected;

uint256 feeToCollect = (amount * feeBps * 10**18) / BPS; 
uint256 amountWithFee = amount + fee; 
IERC20(token).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amountWithFee;

totalDeposited += amount;
feeCollected += fee;

Mappings return :
100 -> totalDeposit
100000000000000000 -> feeCollected

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the math problem correctly, the code should look something like that:

uint decimalFactor = IERC20(token).decimals(); //should return 18 or 6 in your case.

uint256 feeToCollect = (amount * feeBps * 10**decimalFactor) / BPS;

Comment: Correct thanks but I have the following issue when I increment the deposited amount and the fees : 

Let say I deposit 100 tokens and have 2 mapping that keep track of the deposit and fees : 
mapping(address => uint256) public totalDeposited;
mapping(address => uint256) public feeCollected;

uint256 feeToCollect = (amount * feeBps * 10**18) / BPS;
uint256 amountWithFee = amount + fee;

IERC20(token).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amountWithFee; 

totalDeposited += amount; 
feeCollected += fee; 

Mappings return : 100 -> 
totalDeposit 100000000000000000 -> feeCollected

Comment: Add explanation for readers on how calculation works.